# Single-byte ASCII string as extension in an implementation of JavaScript

Tags: types

I'm planning for an implementation of JavaScript. This implementation will provide a memory-safe idiom-rich programming environment with focus on system-programming related goals, and will have a standard library offering features closely resembling the POSIX standard.

One of the considerations, is that I want to have a `char *` type in JS, and I call this `ASCII` - this type can be passed to IO calls that expect data buffers and filesystem calls that expect byte-oriented paths. Anywhere that expect a `String` can receive an `ASCII`.

The name `ASCII` may seem confusing at first, but my explicit goal for this type (when compared to typed arrays) is a byte-oriented type that can function as text. If you were to ask me the advantage of this, I'd say it's more idiomatic than always having to transcoding between typed arrays and `String`.

Now the specific questions I have in mind are:

**Q1**: Should `ASCII` be a super-class of `String` or the other way?

**Q2**: I know Python3 provides `str` and `bytes` types, what are the most important experiences I should learn from them?

**Q3** (bonus): What are the potential conflict that may arise with existing codes?

Comment: If it's meant to represent a byte sequence, name it bytes. ASCII is confusing since it would imply it can only hold <128 byte values while `char*` is any byte value and often shouldn't even hold text.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to [edit] the question in order to *focus* on just one. The first two are somewhat related (though knowing about the second should already answer the first) but the third is at best tangential to the others.

Comment: @mousetail, there are types for raw data in JavaScript. I have the explicit need of a byte-oriented type that work as texts. And I'll note in my docs that "the range 128-255 holds values for an *unspecified* codeset that's only meaningful for the application."

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Perhaps. But that's probably the most valuable answer point of this question. Marking it as a bonus for now.

Comment: Name suggestion: follow Python instead of use `bytes` (edit: I see I have been beaten)

Comment: JavaScript already has array buffer types, like `UInt8Array`. What does your `ASCII` type do that these don't?

Comment: It's not clear what the difference between `ASCII` and `String` is. My first guess would be that `ASCII` can contain only ASCII characters whereas `String` can contain any Unicode character, but you stated that this is not the case. You say that `ASCII` is "a `char *` type" and that it's "byte-oriented," but it's not clear what either of those things means. My next guess is that `ASCII` means a byte string; is that guess correct?

Comment: @TannerSwett Yes, `ASCII` is a byte string that support most of what `String` can do (with 0-127 being ascii and 128-255 being application-specific). Anyway, I dropped this idea, and Q is closed.

Answer (score 1):

### Call it `ffi.c.char[]`

System-programming is about talking very close to the subjacent hardware and OS, which in turn, may have a very exotic and foreign C ABI, in comparison with your memory-safe type system.

Some hardware may have `char` individually addressable and distinct from machine words, so `char*` is really a pointer to the first element of an sequence of `char`s where you can reach each item by pointer arithmetic.

On other systems, where `char` is inexistent, or a direct alias of `int`, `char[]` is really `int[]`, where individual chars may or may not exist packed inside each `int` in some very assembly way. No pointer arithmetic is possible.

In every point where JS string touch a native entry point, JS strings need to be converted to this "native encoding" as an copy, to not violate `String` immutability.

You could have some specializations of `ffi.c.char[]` that encode some native or standard encoding (Ascii, Utf8, PascalU16), but these almost certanly will be mutating (as system ABI doesn't guarantee immutability). For example C strings *returned* from sockets and file I/O are really mutating list of `char`.

**Q1:** No. `char * / char[]` is that it is. An list of integers of size `CHAR_BIT`. No relation whatsoever with immutable [Utf8](https://utf8everywhere.org/) strings.

**Q2:** Never mix one with another. All conversions should be explicit.

**Q3:** Filesystem API. Windows, Linux and MacOs all have various ways to encode filenames. Some of these OS may *require* you to encode `char*` in different ways for different functions.

Answer (score 0):

Q2: The most important lesson learned from Python3, would be not to mix character arrays intended as text, and byte arrays intended as arbitrary data.

I said in the question that "anywhere expecting a `String` can receive an `ASCII`". This is not true. I said in the comment, the range 128-255 in the `ASCII` type's character values are of an *unspecified* codeset that's only meaningful to the application - this precludes using `ASCII` with those values in places accepting `String`s, because it's *unspecified* how to interpret those values as `String` character values (e.g. UTF-8 verses Latin-1).

So Q1: Neither. A common subset of `String` and `ASCII` should be established, and interfaces should be adjusted to accept `String`, `ASCII`, or the said common subset. Consider the "traits" feature from Rust, and use it to support this common subset.

Q3: A lot. For starters, a RegExp replace on `ASCII` with `String` can and will lead to unanticipatable results, and I should work on this more carefully.